# Can you use searchable "tags" in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, tags

I am have a list of business contacts in Excel, like a mini-CRM. One of the fields for each person is where I know them from. For most people, I just have one origin, but some people have multiple. The right solution would be to have a way to add a number of tags into one cell.
Is there a nice way to do this nowadays (without using an add-on)? I would like to be able to search & filter easily.
My current solution is to have a second column, but I might transition to making a semi-colon separated list.

Using a CRM isn't worth it because there isn't really a sales funnel. The purpose of the document is to help me remember who I haven't talked to in a while and what we talked about last time.
One solution is to have a separate table and create a join, but that isn't good for a document that is edited all the time, sometimes on my phone.

Thank you!

Comment: If you use semi-colons then filtering could present so many different combinations. Multiple Origin columns sounds a bit messy too. Showing a desired output may help with ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Using a semi-colons will work just fine together with a Home > Sort & Filter > Filter, like this:

[image]

Click the down arrow next to Origin column and type a few letters of the tag you would like to search for, e.g. "conf":

[image]

Once you hit Okay, all the rows not containing "conf" will be hidden. Hit Home > Sort & Filter > Clear to see all rows again.

**Alternatively** you can also use normal Home > Find & Select > Find, enter your criteria and hit Find All. The search results will display in a list you can click through.  You can work on the spreadsheet while the Find dialog box is open, and you are ready to jump to the next find result.